# jQuery copy text from one input field to another and keep placeholder

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have the following code that copy text from box1 to box2 automatically but would like to keep box2 placeholder value. Any suggestions?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    function onchange() {

        var box1 = jQuery('#g1086-businessname');
        var box2 = jQuery('#g1086-subject');

        box2.val(box1.val());
    }
    jQuery('#g1086-businessname').on('change', onchange);
});
```

Final result should look like:

```
box2= Advertise: box1.val()
```

Comment: UPDATE: box2.val('Advertise: ' + box1.val());  worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating the placeholder instead of value ?

```
box2.attr("placeholder", "Advertise: " + box1.val());
```

Comment: I tried using your suggestion but after submitting form, box1.val is not being added to box2.val, only adds it as a placeholder but not as a value

Comment: Looks like you just needed box2.val('Advertise: ' + box1.val());